# www-data user cannot open a file to write in php

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I have an apache server running as www-data on
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-97-generic x86_64)
In a php file the following line fails with error: Permission denied

```
$f=fopen("detekst.txt","a+");
```

Looking at the permissions:

```
la -al detekst.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 L146584 leerlingen 1364 Feb 15 15:12 detekst.txt
```

and checking groups

```
groups www-data 
www-data : www-data leerlingen
```

I also verified using exec('whoami'); that www-data runs php.

Using a text-editor another member of leerlingen can open the file for writing.

**So I am realy puzzeled, why can't www-data being a member of leerlingen not open the file?**

If I change the permissions of detekst.txt to 0666:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 L146584 leerlingen 1364 Feb 15 15:12 detekst.txt
```

the php code runs fine!!

Also when going back to 664 file permission and change the group to www-data all works fine.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 L146584 www-data 1478 Feb 15 15:45 detekst.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your group ownership of the file in question is not `www-data` when you first attempt to use the file, as such `www-data` user and group don't have write permissions when `644` or `664` are the permissions on the file.  If `www-data` doesn't have user or group ownership of thefile, it falls into the "others" category for permissions, which is read-only (4 = read only perms in chmod language)

Fixing this is to change the group ownership as you saw to `www-data` and then  making sure the permissions are `664` at least because that adds the write permission.

Alternatively, www-data gets added to another group, then you reboot your server to make sure the services all get restarted *correctly* with the new permissions.  In Linux, the services are already started and won't inherit a new permissions group membership until the services are fully restarted under a new session of that 'user', whether it's a system daemon user or not.  So a reboot will help refresh that data on next startup of the web server.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,
But www-data is member of the leerlingen group, so why no ownership by www-data?
Other members of leerlingen have write permissions, and I do not want to make all members of leerlingen member of the group www-data

Comment: You shouldn't be putting www-data into any other groups other than www-data 'cause otherwise it'll be given permissions to things you might not want.  If you added www-data to the group but didn't restart your server to let all the services reboot with the new permissions sets, it won't have access.

Comment: I now solved the problem by using acl, adding www-data as an extra user to all files in the directory tree.

Comment: @JohnVal ACL takes instant effect, yes, but in lieu of ACL, just restart your services with a reboot.  That will make sure `www-data` inherits the proper permissions that it was assigned.

Comment: Thanks again Thomas,
Maybe the reboot or the restart of the apache2 service probably would have solved the issue, but I did not try that.
The directory is shared using Samba and even creating new files give me the extra www-data user using acl. So I'am a happy person at the moment.
Wish you well,

Comment: Thomas, I will reboot :)